# Including another URLconf doesent work, in parent app

Tags: django, django-urls

I'm facing a problem in the last few days with Django URLs and include(). I'm following an online tutorial "Create a chat app using django", and I'm using the newest version of django.

I a project named **mySite**, and an app called **chat**.

chat.urls

```
from django.urls import path
from .import views


urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index),
]
```

chat.views

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):
    return render(request , 'chat/index.html')
```

.

I'm trying to include the chat.URLs into mySite.urls like shown below, but I'm getting an error page after I runserver. I tried to migrate and still is not working.

mySite.URLs

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.urls import include
from chat import urls


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('chat/', include('chat.urls')),
]
```

Comment: Please add the full traceback of the error to your question.

Comment: the code is running perfectly but the page I'm getting a Page not found after running the server

Comment: So `page not found` _or_ `error after runserver`? Does the site work, can you view any of the pages, e.g. index page?

Comment: after running the server I'm getting a PAGE NOT FOUND. https://github.com/ohad1992/chat2. the site manually works

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django Url Pattern Not Being Found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55429392/django-url-pattern-not-being-found)

Comment: his answer is exactly what I did but for some reason, it's still not working

Comment: Please take a look at the **answer**, not the **question** under given link.