# Django app request not found after changing site URLs

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I have a webpage that does an async request on startup to fetch a JSON file:

**controller.js**

```
$.ajax(    
    {
        url: '/get_lines/',
        data_type: 'json',
        success: function(data) 
        {
            fillLinesMenu(JSON.parse(data))
            $("#form-lines option:eq(1)").attr("selected","selected");
            $("#form-lines").selectmenu("refresh")
        }
    }
)
```

**project/field_plot/urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^get_lines/$', views.get_lines, name='get_lines'),
    url(r'^get_plot/$', views.get_plot, name='get_plot'),
    url(r'', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

**project/urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('sky_map/', include('sky_map.urls')),
    path('', include('field_plot.urls')),
]
```

This has been working fine for quite a while. As you can see, I've been working on `field_plot`  - hence the empty url, to simplify page loading - but now I need to assign this app to its specific project-level URL:

**project/urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('sky_map/', include('sky_map.urls')),
    path('field_plot/', include('field_plot.urls')),
]
```

Now I need to load `http://localhost:8000/field_plot/`, as predicted, but changing the last path breaks `/get_lines/` and other URLs I use for AJAX requests. What am I missing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django Url Pattern Not Being Found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55429392/django-url-pattern-not-being-found)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your url has changed from `/get_lines/` to `/field_plot/get_lines/`. The best way to use urls in javascript along with with Django is to **render** the url somewhere in the template as an attribute and get that using javascript.

Somewhere in the template (ideally this would be some button or something that is going to trigger the ajax request, for the sake of an example I would just use a div with an id):

```
<div id="my-url-div" data-url="{% url 'get_lines' %}"></div>
```

Now in your javascript:

```
url: $("#my-url-div").data('url'),
```

Comment: That worked, thanks!!! But is there a cleaner solution? Why can't I just render the URL in place (e.g. without declaring a separate div)?

Comment: Because the JavaScript is in another file (not directly in the template). In fact I believe this is a cleaner solution than rendering directly in JavaScript. (A script writing another script? lots of scope for malicious hackers to make XSS attacks)

Answer (score 1):

Use url name in your javascript request, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/urls/#examples

```js
$.ajax(    
    {
        url: "{% url 'get_lines' %}",
        data_type: 'json',
        success: function(data) 
        {
            fillLinesMenu(JSON.parse(data))
            $("#form-lines option:eq(1)").attr("selected","selected");
            $("#form-lines").selectmenu("refresh")
        }
    }
)
```

Comment: Sadly, it doesn't seem to work... console shows this: `[26/Mar/2021 18:15:45] "GET /field_plot/%7B%%20url%20'get_lines'%20%%7D HTTP/1.1" 200 9233`

Comment: Hmm... it seems that URL is now being matched with the last path, which gets me the page's HTML.