# Page not found (404) django problem!What to do?

Tags: django, django-urls

My project "mysite" has one app "polls" in it

When i run my server i receive 404 error:
[image]

Here is my code:

mysite/settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'polls',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

mysite/urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path("polls/", include("polls.urls")),
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
]
```

polls/views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse


def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello, world. You're at the polls index.")
```

polls/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
]
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django Url Pattern Not Being Found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55429392/django-url-pattern-not-being-found)

Answer (score 1):

in the error message you can see that polls and admin urls are correctly setup and known by django.

But: you make a request to "127.0.0.1:8000/" which is not part of your url-conf:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("polls/", include("polls.urls")),
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
]
```

You can either call

> 127.0.0.1:8000/polls

or

> 127.0.0.1:8000/admin

.

If you expect to see polls app at the root you need to change to:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("/", include("polls.urls")),
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
]
```